# Integral of a total derivative

Tags: calculus, integration

I have seen the "total differential"
$$
d \ln A = -d \ln B/c 
$$
Representing how infinitesimal changes in $A$ are related to infinitesimal changes in $B$.

Someone then took the integral of this total differential to get a relationship between "discrete" changes in $A$ and $B$:
$$
\hat{A} = \hat{B}^{-1/c}  
$$
where $\hat{x} \equiv x'/x$ denotes the proportional change in a variable $x$.

I don't understand how the discrete relationship was derived from the infinitesimal relationship. How does this type of integral work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a heuristic argument commonly used to solve differential equations. Here is a more rigorous explanation:

The differential equation you provided can be written as

$$f'(x) = - \frac{1}{c}$$

where $A = e^{f(x)}$ and $B = e^x$. The general solution to this simple linear differential equation is $f(x) = -\frac{1}{c}x + K$, where $K$ is a constant of integration.

Substituting in the definitions of $A$ and $B$, we have
 $$\log A = - \frac{1}{c} \log B + K$$
which, upon rearrangement, becomes
$$A = B^{-\frac{1}{c}}e^K$$
To solve for the constant of integration $K$, we need initial values $A_0$ and $B_0$. 
Plug these into the general solution to obtain $K = \ln A_0 + \frac{1}{c}\ln B_0$.
Substituting in for $K$, we obtain

$$\frac{A}{A_0} = \left(\frac{B}{B_0}\right)^{-\frac{1}{c}}$$

Comment: Thanks for the very helpful answer. Just with that last bit, should it be $K = \ln A_0 + \frac{1}{c} \ln B$ ?

Comment: Yes! Thanks for the correction.